# reading SVG icon files from disk compared to caching the SVG data?

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, electron, fs

I have an `Electron` app using `d3` and it uses lots of small (50 x 50 px) SVG icons – there could be a 100 or more, with many of duplicates.

The icons are read from disk using `fs` and returned to my `d3` creation routine. The user is able to switch icons when they are editing their project. They could use one or two icons over and over or use any of the 50 icons that are available for them to select from.

I thought I was being clever and wrote an "icon manager" which caches the SVG data in an array after it is read by `fs`, so that if the icon is used multiple times, the "in memory" version can be returned instead of reading from disk again.

I wrote the code over a year ago and had to go into it today to fix an issue. Looking at it now, I am wondering it is all just silly: that `fs` hitting the disk compared to walking through an array is a pointless and even potentially "negative" optimization – that as the number of items in the array grows, the "cost" gets higher.

Am I working too hard here for no reason?

---

```
const fs = require('fs');
const iconLib = [];

exports.getIcon = function (iconName, iconPath) {

    for (let i = 0; i < iconLib.length; i++) {
        if (iconLib[i].iconName == iconName) {
            return iconLib[i].iconData;
        }
    }

    if (fs.existsSync(iconPath)) {
        let data = fs.readFileSync(iconPath, 'utf8');
        iconLib.push({ iconName: iconName, iconData: data })
        return data;
    } else {
        // TODO return something useful
        return 0;
    }
};
```

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this would be a much better fit for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of an array that must be traversed on every retrieval, how about using JavaScript's built-in [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)?

To add an icon to the map:

```
    const iconMap = new Map();

    function cacheIcon(iconName, iconData) {
      iconMap.set(iconName, iconData);
    }
```

To retrieve icon from the map:

```
    iconData = iconMap.get(iconName);
```

Comment: Thanks, I haven't used `Map` before – looks very useful. However it seems to be doing pretty much what I have up top.  From the doc you linked to *A Map object iterates its elements in insertion order — a for...of loop returns an array of [key, value] for each iteration.* – so there is still the walking through an array – compared to reading from disk every time an SVG is needed. That's what I was wondering. I timed it and an `fs` disk read of one of these SVGs averages about .5 ms. I think I 'clevered' myself into some "clever"  stupid code.

Comment: Maps are iterable, but retrieving an element from Map does not require iteration. On the other hand, finding a element in an array always requires iteration. Retrieving with Map is much faster than searching through an array,